# Drupal 7 views 3 - How to Exclude results in one view accordint to another view results

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have 2 views:

1. View list all content by date.
2. View where shows top viewed nodes (2 node only).

How can I exclude nodes from view #1 which is already in the view #2?
Is there any module that will do this? Or does views has this already built in?

Note: 
I'm using the latest dev version of views 3.

Comment: @Danillo, did you solved this problem? I cannot used the views_exclude_previous module..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any module that would do this, but you could just add a filter to not show the top 2 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a module that tries to exclude nodes which have previously been shown on the same page from a view. It's dev for Drupal 7 but seems to do what it's supposed to.
http://drupal.org/project/views_exclude_previous